# Concatenate SQL string with args

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use a default query and then append some conditions. I would like to know how can i concatenate a string while unpacking args.

```
filters = []
if industry:
    filters.append('industry_id')
    filters.append('role_id')
    ...
```

As far as I can see this doesn't work (invalid syntax).

```
print "SELECT city, " + *filters + " FROM histogram"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join` to do what you need:

```
print "SELECT city, " + ', '.join(filters) + " FROM histogram"
```

which prints:

```
SELECT city, industry_id, role_id FROM histogram
```